# std::map: Use only part of keytype for comparison and finding

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I have a map that uses *pairs* of some datatype KT as keys to map to a matrix type, i.e. sth. like

```
std::map<std::pair<KT,KT>, MatType, PairCompare>
```

For comparison I only need the first element of the pair, so PairCompare is very simple

```
struct PairCompare
{
    bool operator()(const std::pair<KT,KT>& lhs,const std::pair<KT,KT>& rhs) const
    {return lhs.first<rhs.first;}
};
```

I would however like to use the whole pair as a key, as I constantly need the second element in operations while iterating through the map.

Sometimes, I also need to find a map entry based on a **single** KT only. Of course I should use a pair of KT in the *find()* routine, but I would like to avoid creating a dummy pair of KT, as I have to do this many times and that could get expensive. I would like to use something like

```
std::map<std::pair<KT,KT>, MatType, PairCompare> mymap;
KT mykey = // ... some implementation of KT;

// fill map

auto it = mymap.find(mykey); // <- will not work of course, but what I would like to use
auto it = mymap.find(std::pair<KT,KT>(mykey,mykey)); // <- what I am using so far (creating a dummy pair)
```

Mykey can in general be both lvalue and rvalue (in my application).

Is there any way of defining a different type of key that contains two KT instances and only uses one for map ordering and also enables finding by **single** KTs that works straight forward? Can it be done with some special comparison object? Maybe there is also a smart way of getting around using pairs of KT as Key at all, but still enabling access to the second KT in map iterations?

Thanks for your help!

P.S.: to be precise, as KT I am using

```
typedef std::vector<int> KT
```

Comment: *"that could get expensive"*. Did you measure that it is too slow for your usecase?

Comment: It is not terribly bad, but it does add an overhead I would like to remove. It is of course more noticeable when KT is a vector of considerable length (like 10 or so).

Comment: But... if the second part of the pair is not used for comparison, it means that Key1 (A,B) and Key2(A,C) are the same (with regards tot he comparison)... than means that only Key1 OR Key2 can be in the map.... So you can use (A,X) to query the map... and add an additional step to check if the key is what you expected.

Comment: Could it be that you actually want a `std::map<KT, std::pair<KT, MatType>>`? It looks like you define a pair to be the key and then try to somehow undo that definition and treat the key as if it was only one single element.

Comment: `std::map<std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>, MatType>` must be the least local object ever. Having two vectors as the key forces each compare operation to require a significant amount of memory lookups, many potentially cache misses.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You are right, this is actually pretty much what I want. I tried to avoid that due to messy iter.second.first and iter.second.second combinations, but it actually seems to be the easiest adaption to my code, although the answer below by utnapistim would work equally well, but would still need some efficiency considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you think of keys as "pair of X,Y". Think of the key as "an object that supports this and that operations":

```
template<typename K1, typename K2>
class Key
{
    K1 v1_;
    boost::optional<K2> v2_;
public:
    Key(K1 v1): v1_{ std::move(v1) }, v2_{} {}
    Key(K1 v1, K2 v2): v1_{ std::move(v1) }, v2_{ std::move(v2) } {}
    bool operator==(const Key<K1,K2>& other)
    {
        if(!v2_ || !other.v2_)
            return v1_ == other.v1_;
        return std::tie(v1_, *v2_) == std::tie(other.v1_, *other.v2_);
    }
    // implement other comparisons, as required
};

using KeyType = Key<int,std::string>;
std::map<KeyType, MatType> YourMap;
// add key comparable by first element:
YourMap[KeyType{0}] = MatType{}; // match KeyType{0, "any string"}
// add key comparable by both elements:
YourMap[KeyType{1, "test"}] = MatType{}; // match KeyType{1, "test"}
```

Attempting to force the key to be a pair here complicates the problem.

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion for the OP.  Very nice.

Comment: That is a very interesting solution! In fact I though of defining some derived class from KT containing yet another KT, but using ``boost::optional`` (which I didn't know about) is of course nicer!